# send and receive SMS and developing a SMS panel

Tags: .net, web-services, sms

i am working on a SMS panel based on .net framework.i just send some messages to my contacts and received their replies.i want to know witch received message is a reply of witch sent message.

ex : if i send A and B messages to 1 contact and then it sends back to me X and Y messages as its reply ,now **how i can find out X is a answer for witch one  A or B messages**.in other hand,what about Y message?!!

I need some ideas or personal experiences about send and receive SMS and generating a SMS panel.

thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried with AT commands?

Comment: @Prasanna , no , what are they ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible. you are talking about two way sms.

you need to use two different services

one is for sending sms, ie http or smpp(need to use the mobile number as senderid on which the reciever replies)

then  on the other hand you  need to configure a sim card reader or develop the application to read those messages

then you can easiely relate them.

Answer (score 1):

SMS is really not very clever: hence its name "short message service".

There's no way to correlate sent messages with replied messages, so I'm afraid you'll need to think of another strategy if this is important to you.

Comment: Can somebody tell me Where I can get the gsmcomm.Dll file

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. SMS messages are stateless.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to tackle it, you can use ATI commands in .Net for this purpose and use GsmComm.dll library to send message, also PDU knowledge is required, you can also see a ready made [library](http://www.rapidsmsserver.com) its name is rapidsmsserver and can ask them how did they implement it or if they could give you some developer license free of cost so you can use it in .net and study it. I dont know much about it, and you can also see many other ready made libraries because most of ATI commands are no more working.

Answer (score 0):

SMS is stateless, you can't track a 'session' (question and reply) using sms since the user can send back a mobile originated short message without any technical way to link it to a received mobile terminated short messages; and that's  why USSD messaging were invented, it is statefull and you can easily track user sessions.